Calculating greeks for a combination of SPX and VIX options
I am trying to properly calculate the delta, vega and theta for an options strategy that involves buying a 90 day ATM SPX put and selling a 90 day ATM VIX call.
Here is what I have done so far:

SPX = 5600
VIX = 16
SPX put Delta = -0.5
VIX call Delta = 0.5
VIX/SPX Beta = -5.42
SPX put Vega = 11.9
VIX call Vega = 0.038
SPX put Theta = -1.17
VIX call Theta = -0.012
The Beta is from 1 year historical daily return data.
Combined Delta = (-0.5) - (-5.42 x 0.5) = 2.21
Combined Vega to SPX = (11.9) - (0.5) = 11.4
Combined Theta = (-1.17) - (-0.012) = -1.16

Perhaps this is correct but I am doubtful because its long the SPX but somehow also long volatility which makes no sense.

Long options in general tend to be long volatility, there is no contradiction.

VIX call vega is SPX volga. VIX call delta is SPX vega.
